# redhat + how to find the oracle JRE version 1.7 from redhat site

Tags: linux, rhel, java, oracle-linux

I am searching the JRE 1.7.x version from red-hat site by yum command

bot not find anything

```
 yum list | grep java | grep "1.7" | grep -i jre
```

no such patch

or maybe redhat not hold JRE 1,7 patches?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable an extra Red Hat Network channel first -- see their guide at https://access.redhat.com/solutions/732883